Apex Class to Parse Response
I am new junior developer and learning apex and could someone review my code and comment on it?
This is my first API response class. Any tips and tricks? what is wrong and what is good?
public with sharing class PostiApiResponseHandler {

    private final static PostiRegisterService REGISTER_SERVICE = new PostiRegisterService();
    private final static PostiProcessingLogSelector LOG_SELECTOR = new PostiProcessingLogSelector();

    public static void parseResponse(String responseBody) {
        Map<String, Object> response = deserializeResponse(responseBody);
        logOperationStatus(response);
        Map<String, Object> message = getMessage(response);
        logMessageDetails(message);

        if (isValidMessage(message)) {
            ProcessingLogData logData = extractProcessingLogData(message);
            processResponseMessage(logData, message);
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> deserializeResponse(String responseBody) {
        return (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
    }

    private static void logOperationStatus(Map<String, Object> response) {
        System.debug('Operation Status: ' + response.get('operationStatus'));
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> getMessage(Map<String, Object> response) {
        return (Map<String, Object>) response.get('message');
    }

    private static void logMessageDetails(Map<String, Object> message) {
        System.debug('Register ID: ' + message.get('id'));
        System.debug('Status: ' + message.get('status'));
        System.debug('Is Approved: ' + message.get('isApproved'));
        System.debug('Last Processing ID: ' + message.get('lastProcessingId'));
        System.debug('Last Processing Date: ' + message.get('lastProcessingDate'));
    }

    private static boolean isValidMessage(Map<String, Object> message) {
        return message != null && message.containsKey('id') && message.containsKey('lastProcessingDate') && message.containsKey('lastProcessingId');
    }

    private static ProcessingLogData extractProcessingLogData(Map<String, Object> message) {
        Datetime lastProcessingDate = Datetime.valueOf((String) message.get('lastProcessingDate'));
        String lastProcessingId = (String) message.get('lastProcessingId');
        String registerId = (String) message.get('id');

        return new ProcessingLogData(registerId, lastProcessingDate, lastProcessingId);
    }

    private static void processResponseMessage(ProcessingLogData logData, Map<String, Object> message) {
        Posti_Processing_Log__c storedLog = LOG_SELECTOR.getLogByRegisterId(logData.registerId);

        if (isNewProcessingData(logData.lastProcessingDate, logData.lastProcessingId, storedLog)) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> updates = (List<Map<String, Object>>) message.get('updates');
            processUpdates(updates, logData.registerId);
            upsertProcessingLog(storedLog, logData);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isNewProcessingData(Datetime lastProcessingDate, String lastProcessingId, Posti_Processing_Log__c storedLog) {
        return storedLog == null || lastProcessingDate > storedLog.Last_Processing_Date__c || !lastProcessingId.equals(storedLog.Last_Processing_Id__c);
    }

    private static void processUpdates(List<Map<String, Object>> updates, String registerId) {
        for (Map<String, Object> updateItem : updates) {
            Datetime processingDate = Datetime.valueOf((String) updateItem.get('processingDate'));
            List<Map<String, Object>> deliverables = (List<Map<String, Object>>) updateItem.get('deliverables');
            UpdateData updateData = new UpdateData(processingDate, deliverables);
            processDeliverables(updateData, registerId);
        }
    }

    private static void processDeliverables(UpdateData updateData, String registerId) {
        for (Map<String, Object> deliverable : updateData.deliverables) {
            if ('RESULT_JSON_FILE_CHANGES'.equals(deliverable.get('deliverableType'))) {
                String deliverableId = (String) deliverable.get('id');
                Integer numberOfChunks = Integer.valueOf((String) deliverable.get('numberOfChunks'));
                PostiRegisterService.downloadDeliverableFiles(registerId, deliverableId, numberOfChunks);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void upsertProcessingLog(Posti_Processing_Log__c storedLog, ProcessingLogData logData) {
        if (storedLog != null) {
            if (!Schema.sObjectType.Posti_Processing_Log__c.fields.Last_Processing_Date__c.isUpdateable() || 
                !Schema.sObjectType.Posti_Processing_Log__c.fields.Last_Processing_Id__c.isUpdateable()) {
                throw new System.DmlException('Insufficient access rights to update Posti_Processing_Log__c');
            }
            storedLog.Last_Processing_Date__c = logData.lastProcessingDate;
            storedLog.Last_Processing_Id__c = logData.lastProcessingId;
            update storedLog;
        } else {
            if (!Schema.sObjectType.Posti_Processing_Log__c.isCreateable()) {
                throw new System.DmlException('Insufficient access rights to create Posti_Processing_Log__c');
            }
            storedLog = new Posti_Processing_Log__c();
            storedLog.External_Id__c = logData.registerId;
            storedLog.Last_Processing_Date__c = logData.lastProcessingDate;
            storedLog.Last_Processing_Id__c = logData.lastProcessingId;
            insert storedLog;
        }
    }

    public static void processDownloadResponse(String responseBody) {
        Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
        List<Map<String, Object>> records = (List<Map<String, Object>>) response.get('records');

        for (Map<String, Object> record : records) {
            String customerId = (String) record.get('customerId');
            Map<String, Object> details = (Map<String, Object>) record.get('details');
            Map<String, Object> personStatus = (Map<String, Object>) details.get('personStatus');
            Map<String, Object> changes = (Map<String, Object>) record.get('changes');

            if ('2'.equals(personStatus.get('sPersonStatusCode'))) {
                PostiAccountUpdater.updateDeceasedStatus(customerId);
            } else {
                if (changes != null) {
                    PostiAccountUpdater.updateAccount(customerId, changes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm just looking for some experienced person validation for my code

Great work, you overall code looks good. Please check my comments here https://www.decodeforce.com/code/-O-5HZaDK33NaNL3W1Oe
